# Is the following function differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis

Suppose $ C \subseteq \Bbb R^n $ is bounded, and define $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ by $$f(x) = \sup_{y \in C}\|x-y\|, $$ where the norm is euclidean distance. Is $f$ differentiable?

Comment: Is there some condtions on $C$? In this way is too vague...

Comment: There have to be *some* conditions on $C$. Boundedness, at least.

Comment: No there is no such condition given. The question was first to show that $f(x)$ is convex  and then the second part asked if it is differentiable.

Comment: @Tomás I don't think convexity of C will be used in proving f to be convex.

Comment: @Tomás Show $f(\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha) x_2) \leq \alpha f(x_1) + (1-\alpha) f(x_2)$. Nothing is used about C in this proof. lhs will become $\sup\limits_{y \in C}\|(\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha) x_2 - y \|$

Comment: Put $C=\Bbb R^n$. The function then isn't even defined anywhere. There need to be some conditions on $C$.

Comment: @Tomás $f(x)$ is $R^n \rightarrow R$.

Comment: @CameronBuie You can add when f is defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarily -- consider $n=1$ and $C=[0,1]$. Then $f$ fails to be differentiable at $\frac 12$.

It might be true if we restrict to convex $C$ and only consider differentiability in the interior of $\mathbb R^n\setminus C$.

Answer (score 2):

If it is asked that way, taking $n=1$, $C=\{0\}$  than 
$f(x)=|x|$ which isn't differentiable in $0$